# sparksql - convert string with timezone to UTC

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val someDF = Seq(
        (8, "2019-12-11T00:00:00.451086451+09"),
        (64, "2017-08-09T13:12:35.283018201-04"),
        (-27, "2019-12-01T23:00:00.484072842Z")
      ).toDF("number", "tt")
someDF.createOrReplaceTempView("t")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM t").show(20, false)
```

ignore the first column.
how to convert the 2nd column values into timestamp data type (in UTC) using purely sparksql ?
i tried below but it returned null and i can't find a way to surround 'T' with quotes :

```
spark.sql("SELECT tt, to_timestamp(tt,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSX') n FROM t").show(20, false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the format string.

`spark.sql("SELECT tt, to_timestamp(tt) n FROM t").show(20, false)`
returns

```
+--------------------------------+--------------------------+
|tt                              |n                         |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------+
|2019-12-11T00:00:00.451086451+09|2019-12-10 15:00:00.451086|
|2017-08-09T13:12:35.283018201-04|2017-08-09 17:12:35.283018|
|2019-12-01T23:00:00.484072842Z  |2019-12-01 23:00:00.484072|
+--------------------------------+--------------------------+
```